# Sonarqube analysis total time/duration [SonnarScanner for Maven]

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using Sonarqube 8.9 LTS with SonarScanner for Maven.

When we run any scan with SonarScanner for Maven, the normal output is:

```
[INFO] CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=3287ms
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 2397ms, dir size=64 MB
[INFO] Analysis report compressed in 25206ms, zip size=24 MB
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 1866ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://127.0.0.1:9000/dashboard?id=project_id
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/ce/task?id=task_id
[INFO] Analysis total time: 18:30.103 s
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19:37 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-22T02:23:22Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where do i find this information after the scan is completed?
I can't find it in the web ui or the rest api.

Answer (score 1):

This information is not stored on the server.

I did ask the same question on sonar community and got the following response:

> You won’t find this stored on the server; it’s not sent to the server
> and is only available where you see it: in the client-side analysis
> logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are

- **Global Administrators** can view the status of Background task at `Administration > Projects > Background Tasks`.
- **Project administrators** can see the tasks for a project at `Project Settings > Background Tasks`

More details in here [Background Tasks](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/background-tasks/)

Comment: This only shows info about the process AFTER the code scan.
I need the SCAN info.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: What SCAN info you needs to see ? You can run the sonar analysis in verbose mode to see all the info.

Comment: I just got this response from sonar community:
"Hi,

You won’t find this stored on the server; it’s not sent to the server and is only available where you see it: in the client-side analysis logs. Would you mind sharing why you want it?

 
Ann"

Thanks for trying to help.